# Not found custom security config in controller test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-security

I write test for get method of my controller and create custom config for authentication but when run test , generated default password and present this error :

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = GET
  Request URI = /android-guard-infos/1
   Parameters = {}
      Headers = {}
         Body = <no character encoding set>
Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST=DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost/android-guard-infos/1]}

Handler:
         Type = null

Async:
Async started = false
 Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
         Type = null

ModelAndView:
    View name = null
         View = null
        Model = null

FlashMap:
   Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 401
Error message = Unauthorized
      Headers = {WWW-Authenticate=[Basic realm="Realm"], X-Content-    Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
 Content type = null
         Body = 
Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
      Cookies = []

 java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
 Expected :200   
 Actual   :401

at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:55)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:619)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:178)
at ir.fidar.seclab.controllersTest.AndroidGuardInfoControllerTest.getOneTest(AndroidGuardInfoControllerTest.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

my dependency for test and security is :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and my security config class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(getProvider());

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/**","/roles/**","/privileges/**").hasAuthority("manager")
            .antMatchers("/android-guard-infos/**","process-queues/**",
                    "/risk-android-infos/**","/summery-infos/**",
                    "/virus-total-infos/**","/vt-process-queues/**").permitAll();
}


@Bean
public AppAuthenticationProvider getProvider(){
    AppAuthenticationProvider provider = new AppAuthenticationProvider(appUserDetailsService);
    return provider;
}
```

}

my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AndroidGuardInfoController.class)
//@Import(AppSecurityConfig.class)
public class AndroidGuardInfoControllerTest  {


@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
private AndroidGuardInfoService controller;

@Test
public void getOneTest() throws Exception {
    AndroidGuardInfo data = new AndroidGuardInfo();


    Mockito.when(controller.getOne(1L)).thenReturn(data);
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/android-guard-infos/1")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

}

I trying resolve this error by add  @Import(AppSecurityConfig.class) but 
change error to `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` Caused by `Error creating bean` .

can you guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@Import(AppSecurityConfig.class)` failed on below bean dependency injection. Expected.

```
@Autowired
private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;
```

This is because you are trying to access configurations which are pointing to src packages by default.

In order to use the same configuration in `test` directory **(out of /src scope**) then either you explicitly specify the *package scanning* , *component scan* definitions in your `AppSecurityConfig.java` or try adding test specific configuration where you define test level configuration with package definitions.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "YOUR_PACKAGES"
})
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class TestAppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(getProvider());

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/**","/roles/**","/privileges/**").hasAuthority("manager")
            .antMatchers("/android-guard-infos/**","process-queues/**",
                    "/risk-android-infos/**","/summery-infos/**",
                    "/virus-total-infos/**","/vt-process-queues/**").permitAll();
}


@Bean
public AppAuthenticationProvider getProvider(){
    AppAuthenticationProvider provider = new AppAuthenticationProvider(appUserDetailsService);
    return provider;
}
}
```

And then try to import this in your test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AndroidGuardInfoController.class)
@Import(TestAppSecurityConfig.class)
public class AndroidGuardInfoControllerTest  {
```

Comment: I saw in your code you  create 'TestAppSecurityConfig' class, is that means i must create separate config for test?

Comment: @farzane yes. Its only for your Test context to your test cases.

Comment: i do that as you say but it gave me error about the Repository that is in the path i set it in Componentscan

Comment: please see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933081/failed-to-load-applicationcontext-error-in-during-controller-test-and-inabilit