# "Failed to load ApplicationContext" error in during controller test and Inability to create bean

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, compiler-errors

I try to write a test for my Controller but in first time , when I run my test , it not found my security configuration ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916948/not-found-custom-security-config-in-controller-test/55918376?noredirect=1#comment98497229_55918376)) . I add security Configuration to test package as `TestAppSecurityConfig` class and use `@ComponentScan` on this class . But I think I've made it wrong Because I get "Failed to load ApplicationContext" error .

Do you know how to fix it?

ClassPath:

"main"

> ir.fidar.seclab.security.config.AppSecurityConfig //real security config
>   ir.fidar.seclab.security.AppAuthenticationProvider
>   ir.fidar.seclab.security.AppUserDetails
>   ir.fidar.seclab.security.service.AppUserDetailsService
>   ir.fidar.seclab.service.impl.PrivilegeServiceImpl

"test"

> ir.fidar.seclab.config.TestAppSecurityConfig
>   ir.fidar.seclab.controllersTest.AndroidGuardInfoControllerTest

TestAppSecurityConfig class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ir.fidar.seclab"})
public class TestAppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(getProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/**","/roles/**","/privileges/**").hasAuthority("manager")
            .antMatchers("/android-guard-infos/**","process-queues/**",
                    "/risk-android-infos/**","/summery-infos/**",
                    "/virus-total-infos/**","/vt-process-queues/**").permitAll();
}


@Bean
public AppAuthenticationProvider getProvider(){
    AppAuthenticationProvider provider = new AppAuthenticationProvider(appUserDetailsService);
    return provider;
}
```

}

my dependency for test and security is :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AndroidGuardInfoController.class)
@Import(TestAppSecurityConfig.class)
public class AndroidGuardInfoControllerTest  {


@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
private AndroidGuardInfoService controller;

@Test
public void getOneTest() throws Exception {
    AndroidGuardInfo data = new AndroidGuardInfo();


    Mockito.when(controller.getOne(1L)).thenReturn(data);
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/android-guard-infos/1")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

}

and error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'privilegeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'privilegeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ir.fidar.seclab.dao.PrivilegeRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'privilegeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ir.fidar.seclab.dao.PrivilegeRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ir.fidar.seclab.dao.PrivilegeRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
... 56 more
```

Comment: this is because you have not enabled repository scan. e.g. if you are using JPA than enable jpa repository scanning. @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
                            "ir.fidar.seclab.dao"
                        }

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have to enable repository scanning which is missing from your configuration.

e.g. If you are using JPA repositories than you have enable JPA repositories as follows,

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "ir.fidar.seclab.dao" } )
```

Comment: but in main app this error doesn't appear and as same i didn't enable jpa Repository scan, it must enable just in tests?

Comment: this error just appears in test in main app i have no errors and every thing is running well